# Manipulate txt searching for three pattern (sed,awk,pcregrep)

Tags: python, awk, sed, text-processing, pcregrep

i have got this text file

```
AAAA
1234
title example
Lorem Ipsum
FF
AAAA
1234
title example
€330 - Roma
FF
```

I want to extract from this file only the txt that:

```
START WITH AAAA
HAS Euro SYmbol
END WITH FF
```

In this case i want to match only that

```
AAAA
1234
title example
€330 - Roma
FF
```

I tried with different solution
i used

```
sed -e '/AAAAs/,/europ/,/FF/!d' testfile.txt
```

but it extract all txet between AAAA and FF

How can i solve it?

Thanks for help

EDIT:

between euro line and FF there could be some text. i don't know how many lines..

```
AAAA
1234
title example
€330 - Roma
Some text with \n, comma symbol etc etc
FF
```

i wat to extract the txt between AAAA and FF

Comment: Does the line with `€` always occur at 4th line from `AAAA` and just before `FF`?

Comment: the structure is a little bit tricky, AAAA-A title, euro symbol, text containg \n, and FF

Comment: _tricky_ as in _it need NOT be that way_ all the time?

Comment: Can you try my answer to see if it helped?

Answer (score 3):

With sed:

```
 sed -n '/^AAAA/{:a;N;/\nFF/!ba; /€/p}' file
```

**How it works:**

- `/^AAAA/`: from lines starting with `AAAA`
- `:a`: label `a` for upcoming loop
- `N`: adds next line to pattern space
- `/\nFF/!`: if newline followed by `FF` is not found,
- `:ba`: loops to `a` label to add next line to pattern space
- `/€/p`: outputs if `€` is found

**Edit:**

As suggested by @potong in comments, with GNU sed you can also use the `M` command to match your regex in multi-line mode:

```
sed -n '/^AAAA/{:a;N;/^FF/M!ba; /€/p}' file
```

Comment: If using GNU sed `sed -n '/^AAAA/{:a;N;/^FF/M!ba; /€/p}' file also may appeal.

Comment: @user3720159 Glad it works. I added some explanations.

Comment: @SLePort - Can you please explain this part - "!ba; "

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR `ba` is for looping(`b` for branch) to `a` label. I added a line for it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

A nice quick way would be to use grep with multiple search patterns.  So for your needs:

```
grep -B3 -A1 -e '€' test.txt
```

This will find the Euro symbol, and print the 3 lines before and the 2 after, however this will only work if you expect the file to remain in the same patter, i.e AAAA and FF occur the same amount of lines above and below.

Comment: As a side note, there are lots of other ways to do this, including python re, however for searching through large data, I've found grep to be the fastest.

Comment: Can you please have a look at OP's expected output? Your command gives `AAAA
FF
AAAA
€330 - Roma
FF
`

Comment: Oh, I see - between the two parameters.  Ok I'll edit that.

Comment: in this way it doesnt return the number 1234

Answer (score 1):

Python is a procedural language, so it may require more text but is simpler for complex things. Here you should:

- start storing when you see a AAAA line
- end storing when you see a FF line and

  - only keep the stored text if it contains a $

That can be translated in Python as:

```
with open(infile) as fd:
    processing = False
    txt = None
    euro = None
    for line in fd:
        if line.strip() == 'AAAA':     # start processing
            processing = True
            txt = ""
            euro = False
        if processing:
            txt += line                # store all lines between AAAA and FF
            if '€' in line: euro = True    # is an € present ?
            if line.strip() == 'FF':   # stop processing
                processing = False
                if euro:               # only print if a € was found
                    print(txt)
```

Not as compact as an awk, grep or sed script, but simple to write, read and maintain

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>5' file

AAAA
1234
title example
€330 - Roma
FF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/\xe2\x82\xac/{printf RS $0}' RS=AAAA file
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Euro SYmbol  => € => \xe2\x82\xac

echo €|hexdump -C

Comment: Why don't you use /€330/ instead of something cryptic?
Like this: awk '/€330/{printf RS $0}' RS=AAAA file